# Check IDs from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables: “rota” (1) and “volunteer” (2). The first name and last name columns are in (2), but the shifts in (1). With the following query I am able to see the names of those who have submitted their shifts, but I would like to see those who have not. Can't figure it out how. Any help?

```
SELECT COUNT(rota.shift_id), rota.volunteer_id, volunteer.firstname, volunteer.lastname
FROM rota 
INNER JOIN volunteer ON rota.volunteer_id=volunteer.id
GROUP BY volunteer_id;
```

Answer (score 4):

You want a `LEFT JOIN` -- and to put the `volunteer` table first because you want all the rows from that table:

```
SELECT v.id, v.firstname, v.lastname, COUNT(r.shift_id), rota.volunteer_id
FROM volunteer v LEFT JOIN
     rota r 
     ON r.volunteer_id = v.id
GROUP BY v.id;
```

Note that you do not need to include all columns from `volunteer` in the `GROUP BY` because `v.id` uniquely identifies each row in the result set.

EDIT:

If you want volunteers with no shifts, then use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM volunteer v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM rota r 
                  WHERE r.volunteer_id = v.id
                 );
```

You can equivalently do this with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT v.id, v.firstname, v.lastname
FROM volunteer v LEFT JOIN
     rota r 
     ON r.volunteer_id = v.id
WHERE r.volunteer_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. See below what I finally did.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
SELECT volunteer.id, volunteer.firstname, volunteer.lastname, COUNT(rota.shift_id), rota.volunteer_id, volunteer.firstname, volunteer.lastname 
FROM volunteer 
LEFT JOIN rota ON rota.volunteer_id = volunteer.id 
GROUP BY volunteer.id
HAVING COUNT(rota.shift_id) = 0;
```

Comment: . . This is not a good approach.  You are doing an unnecessary aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gordon, your solution above works fantastic!